# Neural network for peak identification problem not training successfully

Tags: neural-network, theano

I'm trying to build a program that can identify peaks in a signal.

It's my first attempt at machine learning so I'm starting with a toy problem where I'm generating a gaussian curve of random width and position with a small amount of added noise and trying to identify what part of the signal looks like a peak but I'm facing some issues. I'm using Theano+Lasagne and adapted my code from the MNIST.py example. Here's an example of what I feed to my code and what I get as a result:

[image]

My idea is to feed the signal (1D vector of 512 values) to a simple neural network composed of 5 dense layers (3 linear followed by 2 sigmoids) of 128 neuron each. And training it on tens of thousands of generated examples.

But the issue I'm facing is that no matter what I try regarding weight initialization or learning parameters I always converge to the same result : a network that seem to only spit out the average value of the "goal output" of all the examples it was trained with.

I would assume that given the structure of my neural net and what data I'm feeding to it, it would easily converge to something that does a bit of averaging and thresholding to give me something reasonably close to the expected output.

Is that foolish to assume ? Or am I missing something important ?

Comment: a convolution would accomplish this much quicker/easier.  Why do you want to use a neural net?

Comment: Is your output layer and training target/label data 512 samples too (the graph implies it is, or is it downsampled)? Either way then yes this looks like a simple problem, and I would expect a network could be trained simply to resolve it. Most likely you have one or more mistakes in your use of the NN library - bad setup, incorrect hyper-parameter etc. Unfortunately the graph is not enough diagnostic for those kind of problems - it's a bug hunt and you will need to share your code.

Comment: @NeilSlater The output is indeed 512 samples. I'll try to keep on poking my code to find where it fails then.

Comment: There are heaps of peak-finding routines out there, and none of them are based on neural networks. There's a reason for that. Try looking up peak detection based on the continuous wavelet transform.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski I think the clue to the question is in "so I'm starting with a toy problem". This is no different to training a first network to classify XOR or a RNN to add in binary IMO. The question is about the NN, not about solving the data problem. Perhaps the title could do with a change to better reflect the goal?

Comment: @NeilSlater I guess? "I'm trying to build a program that can identify peaks in a signal." is a pretty strong opener

Comment: I have changed the title based on my assumption, to avoid attracting (accurate) criticism that NNs are the wrong tool for the problem. If actually you are looking for help with identifying peaks in data, then please rollback or edit as you wish

Comment: @NeilSlater Seems fair to me. My issue is indeed with the neural network I'm working with, and not with peak detection in general.